# How serious is a badly kinked suction line on a split system A/C?

Tags: hvac

A friend had me remove a section of drywall to see why there was moisture damage at the baseboard height on one wall.

I found the refrigerant line that runs from outside compressor to attic mounted air handler was poorly insulated and dripping in the wall cavity.

Upon close inspection I also found that the larger copper line,the suction line, was nearly flat where a 90 degree turn to the outside was bent into it.

I estimate 10% of the capacity of the line is available due to the severity of this bend.

The A/C is brand new and cooling well.

The Home was built 15 years ago and this is the third AC replacement. The kinked line was done during construction.

I believe this kinked line is the cause of premature failure of the last 2 units and if left unfixed will lead to a third unit failing.

Tell me what can happen to a system over time in a case where the 3/4 suction line is crushed like this.

[image]

Edit: the kinked section was cut out and new line put in.

Here is a photo of how bad the kink was. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A kink in the line starves the system and it should be pumped down cut out and a 45 or 90 put in its place. If it did not matter they would not use a line that much larger On the suction side.

Comment: When you say starves the system are you referring to the compressor being deprived of lubricant?

Comment: mainly it makes the compressor work harder. it's costing you money.

Comment: I would suggest trying to breathe through a straw. This is the difference the large line allows the flow at low pressures some even are sub atmospheric so the large line that supplies the compressor is like a snorkel size and it has been pinched down to a straw, the oil will make it back but the increased workload is costing you $ and wear and tear on the compressor.

Comment: That should not take long they can close the discharge valves on the compressor start it and run it until the suction is at a vacuum (gauge reading) a quick clean and cut , purge with n2 sweat, pressure check then pull a vacuum with a pump if it is not open for more than a couple of minutes the vacuum only takes a couple of minutes because no moisture has had time to get in the system. If it is open as far as easy to get to a good tech could do this in many cases under 2 hours and with a big vacuum pump possibly under 1.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting gurgling and bubbling noises in my new system! (5 multi splits) The noise came from one unit only.  The first company I called could not find the reason and told me to live with it. When another company came around, I told the service guy about the problem. He found the pipe to an indoor unit had a kink, causing all these problems.
Go figure.